# D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain fails with S_False on different computer

Tags: c++, directx-11

I've made quite a bit of progress since the last time I asked a question. I've got a really cool build now with a terrain mesh with mountains and lakes:
[LakeAndMountains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYihB.jpg)

I made a release build, debugged it, and now it works just fine on my computer. I can take the application folder and move it around on my computer and run the .exe file with no issues. However, when I copy the application directory over to my other computer (and my friend's computer), it fails during the D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain step with an HR of S_False.

For both my other computer and my friend's computer, it triggers only the if(failed(hr)) after the create function is called, and it says dev/devcon/swapchain are all NULL. Because they are all null, when it hits the function from swapchain, it crashes with an access violation error.

I searched for a few days looking for solutions, but I have yet to see one that had the S_FALSE occur. I tried some of the more straightforward answers but got nothing. All the computers are running 64bit on 64 bit OS, all have DirectX12, all are high end gaming PCs, my other computer actually has VS2017CE as well set up for c++ game programming, but they both still fail on that line. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could give me some guidance on where to begin deciphering why a release build works on my computer but not on anyone else's computer. Here is the code where it gets initialized, as well as the code for the window creation (code is excerpted to just the relevant parts of the functions):

WinMain:

```
// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine,
int nCmdShow)
{
//MessageBox(NULL, "Start of WinMain", "WinMain", 0);
// the handle for the window, filled by a function
HWND hWnd;
// this struct holds information for the window class
WNDCLASSEX wc;

//Screen size variables
long screenWidth = 1280;
long screenHeight = 720;
UINT screenWidthUINT = 1280;
UINT screenHeightUINT = 720;

// clear out the window class for use
ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

// fill in the struct with the needed information
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
//wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass1";

// register the window class
RegisterClassEx(&wc);

RECT wr = { 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight };    // set the size, but not the position
AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);    // adjust the size

// create the window and use the result as the handle
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
    "WindowClass1",
    "Game",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    0,    // x-position of the window
    0,    // y-position of the window
    wr.right - wr.left,    // width of the window
    wr.bottom - wr.top,    // height of the window
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);

// display the window on the screen
ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
//MessageBox(NULL, "called ShowWindow", "WinMain", 0);

/*****************************************
//  GAME ENGINE INITIALIZATION
******************************************/
//Need to initialize the graphics engine. This passes the window pointer through the
//game engine to the D3D engine so it knows what window to look at.
//MessageBox(NULL, "Calling InitGraphics", "WinMain", 0);
InitGraphics(hWnd);
```

InitGraphics:

```
//DEVICE CREATION
#include Windows.h
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <D3Dcompiler.h>
#include <dxgi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")

#include "DirectXDeviceEngine.h"

using namespace DirectX;

InitGraphics(HWND hWnd)
{
//call at start to initialize D3DX
if (hWnd == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "hWnd was NULL", "DirectXDeviceEngine", 0);
}

HRESULT hr;
//initialize swap chain
//Describe our Buffer
DXGI_MODE_DESC bufferDesc;

ZeroMemory(&bufferDesc, sizeof(DXGI_MODE_DESC));

bufferDesc.Width = winWidth;
bufferDesc.Height = winHeight;
bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
bufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
bufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
bufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

// create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

// clear out the struct for use
ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

// fill the swap chain description struct
scd.BufferCount = 1;                                    // one back buffer
scd.BufferDesc = bufferDesc;
scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                               // how many multisamples
scd.SampleDesc.Quality = 1;
scd.Windowed = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;  // windowed/full-screen mode
scd.Flags = 0;

// create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
dev = NULL;
devcon = NULL;
swapchain = NULL;

hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
    NULL, //null
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, //driver type
    NULL, //handle to a software rasterizer, should be null if driver type isn't software
    NULL, //UINT device creation flags, can be ORed together
    NULL, //D3D Feature level, when NULL defaults to 11.0-9.1 feature levels
    NULL, //the number of elements in the D3D feature level array
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION, //set to D3D11_SDK_VERSION
    &scd, //reference to the swap chain desc
    &swapchain, //reference to the pointer to the swap chain
    &dev, //reference to the pointer to the device
    NULL, //returns a reference to the first supported element in the feature level array
    &devcon); //reference to the pointer to the device context
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    //CODE FALLS INTO THIS BLOCK ON OTHER COMPUTER
    MessageBox(NULL, "Create Device and SwapChain FAILED", "DirectXDeviceEngine", 0);
    if (swapchain == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "swapchain was NULL", "DirectXDeviceEngine", 0);
    }
    if (dev == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "dev was NULL", "DirectXDeviceEngine", 0);
    }
    if (devcon == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "devcon was NULL", "DirectXDeviceEngine", 0);
    }
}
//prepare buffers
// get the address of the back buffer
ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
//VVVV CODE THEN CRASHES ON NEXT LINE BECAUSE SWAPCHAIN IS NULL VVVV
swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);
```

Thanks in advance.

----UPDATE 2017/09/08-----
So I swapped some code around but I still get the error on the other computer. Current code looks like this:

```
//call at start to initialize D3DX
if (&hWnd == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "hWnd was NULL", "DirectXDeviceEngine", 0);
}

HRESULT hr;

// create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
dev = NULL;
devcon = NULL;
swapchain = NULL;

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL lvl[] = {
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1 };

DWORD createDeviceFlags = 0;
hash ifdef _DEBUG
createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
hash endif

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL fl;
hr = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr,
    createDeviceFlags, lvl, _countof(lvl),
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &dev, &fl, &devcon);
if (hr == E_INVALIDARG)
{
    hr = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr,
        createDeviceFlags, &lvl[1], _countof(lvl) - 1,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &dev, &fl, &devcon);
}
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Create Device Failed", "DirectXDeviceEngine", 0);
}

IDXGIDevice * dxgiDevice = 0;
dev->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void **)& dxgiDevice);

IDXGIAdapter * dxgiAdapter = 0;
dxgiDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void **)& dxgiAdapter);

IDXGIFactory * dxgiFactory = 0;
dxgiAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void **)& dxgiFactory);

//initialize swap chain
//Describe our Buffer
DXGI_MODE_DESC bufferDesc;

ZeroMemory(&bufferDesc, sizeof(DXGI_MODE_DESC));

/*bufferDesc.Width = winWidth;
bufferDesc.Height = winHeight;
bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
*/
bufferDesc.Width = 0;
bufferDesc.Height = 0;
bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
bufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
bufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
bufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

// create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

// clear out the struct for use
ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

// fill the swap chain description struct
scd.BufferCount = 1;                                    // one back buffer
scd.BufferDesc = bufferDesc;
scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                               // how many multisamples
scd.SampleDesc.Quality = 1;
scd.Windowed = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;  // windowed/full-screen mode
scd.Flags = 0;

hr = dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChain(dev, &scd, &swapchain);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
//fails here
    MessageBox(NULL, "Create Swap Chain Failed", "DirectXDeviceEngine", 0);
}

if (dxgiDevice != NULL)
{
    dxgiDevice->Release();
}
if (dxgiAdapter != NULL)
{
    dxgiAdapter->Release();
}
if (dxgiFactory != NULL)
{
    dxgiFactory->Release();
}

//prepare buffers
// get the address of the back buffer
ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);
```

So, there is still some weird stuff happening here I'm not getting. If someone has an example of how to use FindClosestMatchingMode properly, I'd really appreciate it.

There is one other really peculiar thing though. When I am in the debugger on my laptop, the variable hWnd has a value, but the compiler says that it is Unused and can't display a value for it. Is this normal or could this be the source of the problem as hWnd is used in the Swap Chain Description? How can hWnd be bad/unused on the other computer but not on my desktop?

Thanks again.

Comment: looks like it's failing because you didn't specify valid creation flags when invoking D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain. If you look at this enum D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_FLAG it doesn't have any value which equals to 0: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476107(v=vs.85).aspx If you are not using deferred device context then at least specify D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED, might solve your problem

Comment: I tried that just now but I got the same error, S_FALSE return in the hr with no additional information. Its weird because the release works on my computer just fine but not when I move it to a different computer. Which is also weird because I can move the release folder around to other places and it still works fine on my comp.

Comment: 0 is a valid value for creation flags, although you shouldn't really be using ``NULL`` for something that's just the value 0. That's of course is why C++11 strongly encourages using ``nullptr`` instead of legacy ``NULL`` which would generate an error/warning for the non-pointer usages.

Comment: Have you tried enabling ``D3D11_CREATE_DEBUG_FLAG`` on the impacted systems and looking for output? Generally speaking ``D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain`` is an older legacy function; see [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/) for details on modern device creation.

Comment: Note that ``S_FALSE`` is still considered a successful return (it would pass testing with the ``SUCCEEDED`` macro and would not with ``FAILED``). I'm not sure exactly what it means in this case, but I suspect it's related to the use of fullscreen exclusive mode and MSAA: Perhaps it's creating a swapchain with a 'close' mode rather than an exact match which often happens with refresh rates.

Comment: Also note that you are *assuming* that the adapter in question supports a display mode of ``winWidth``, ``winHeight``, and 1/60 Hz refresh rate with RGBA 32-bit. That may or may not be true, which is why for exclusive fullscreen you have to enumerate the output display modes and then either find an exact match or use ``FindClosestMatchingMode``. Exclusive fullscreen mode is quite complex to get robustly right, which is partly why it's often better to just use a windowed mode with a borderless window (a.k.a 'fake fullscreen') by default. Try enumerating the display modes on the systems.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed replies, Chuck. I will have to take a closer look at your way of setting up Direct X 11. I'm curious about your statements regarding full screen and adapter settings. When I start the application on my computer, it is not in full screen, it is in a window. I can change it into full screen with alt+enter. I'll look into what you have discussed over the next few days and figure it out.

Comment: As @ChuckWalbourn mentioned, it is very likely that DXGI will match a refresh rate, it's pretty rare that display monitors are exactly 60Hz, to you need to go find the closest numerator / denominator (just for example, on my laptop for full HD it reports, 152840000/2547000, which is 60.0079)

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Hello, I finally got some free time again to look into this. I have updated my code to more closely match what you have, but no luck. It still works just fine on my computer, but not on my laptop. I have not implemented the FindClosestMatchingMode code as I have not been able to find an example of it. See original post for updated code.

Answer (score 0):

So I FINALLY found the cause of the issue. For some reason, the Count 4 Quality 1 MSAA was not working on the other computer. When I set it to 1/0, it ran perfectly. I'll need to look into how to properly enumerate the MSAA stuff so it can be adjusted depending on the computer.